# PHP Param + URL Rewrite + Domain Name

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm planning to build a site. For example, let's say that I'm building a website (cardealer.com) that list all car dealers. Each car dealer will buy their own domain. Data example :

```
| DealerA | dealera.com |
| DealerB | dealerb.com |
```

Ok now the situation will be like : If I go to the url dealera.com, I will see cardealer.com?domain=DealerA .

Is it possible? If it is, How can I achieve this? Thank you

Comment: I don't get your question, if dealera.com points to cardealer.com you will, but otherwise you won't.

Comment: Please show what you've got so far

Comment: Imagine how rich I would be if I could make Google's traffic redirect to my own site. No, you cannot achieve this unless you own the domain and have full access to the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's very simple. There are a few ways to achieve this. One way to set the URL/parameterforwarding directly in the domainsettings. Another way would be to write redirects in your .htaccess files (mod rewrite). The only thing is: you need to have access to all domain settings or webspaces/servers.

Comment: Your second option is wrong. If he doesn't own the domain his own .htaccess won't do squat.

Answer (score 0):

The owner of dealera.com will need to have his domain pointing to your IP, additionally you will have to configure dealera.com as an alias for your domain, if it is name-based (not ip-based).

On handling the requests you will have different options. You can hide the second domain name (cardealer.com) via internal rewriting or a frameset, or you could use an explicit redirect to your own domain, if the common site should be presented under that name.